# in a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline, how can I set it so it only builds certain branches during a scan?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi-branch pipeline and set up the scanning every 1 minute (for testing). I've additionally setup the job's property this way. I want to build ALL branches with changes during a scan, **except** `feature/*` branches.
[image]

Sure enough the `feature/*` branches' builds are skipped. However, the `master` branch is also not being built, even though the scan logs says it detects changes.

```
  Checking branch master
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: master (24590edaa934ecf091dcc372c0f6ce536c1e2f1c → e490fbf1779e28761f996964c7b9e6e4a2e8b909)
Did not schedule build for branch: master
```

**UPDATE**
I also tried putting `feature/*` where I have `master`, like this, to no avail.
[image]
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration displayed on your screenshot means that Jenkins will suppress the builds on master branch, if the changes are detected by indexing (e.g. by running the multibranch scan, that produces the log you show). So this looks like an opposite thing to the one you wanted to achieve.

You need to put a regex that matches your feature branches instead of "master" to that field.

Also, have a look at the setting "Exclude branches that are also listed as PRs" - that will automatically skip the feature branches if they have any open PRs, so the more valuable PR builds could be built instead.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, where I put `feature/*` instead of `master`, but that doesn't build anything either. It's just confusing because the text box says "Branches to build automatically"

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation, this seems to work.
[image]